# SQL Server conecction with jdbc eclipse

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, jdbc

I have the following code to connect to my database in SQL Server:

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-G8057U8\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=Vaporizadores;integratedSecurity=true;";
        DBConection=DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        DBStatement = DBConection.createStatement();
        System.out.println("Conexion exitosa");
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Conexion fallida");
    }
}
```

when I run it I get "Conexion fallida", meaning that an exception was catched. I've tried different urls but I still can't connect to my DB. I know very little about jdbc and sql server, so it may be a stupid error.

Comment: do a,
catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } and give the result...

Comment: Don't specify both port (1433) and instance name (SQLEXPRESS). They are mutually exclusive. Remove the port number.

Comment: @dilanSachi Better yet: `catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(System.out); }`

Comment: `integratedSecurity=true` requires the `.dll` file in the PATH. Is it there?

Comment: @Andreas thanx for the tip

Comment: I concur with *dilanSachi*: Print the actual error message, so you can see **why** it failed.

Comment: Can you put `e.printStackTrace()` into the catch block and post the stacktrace? The connection may fail for different reasons though- either the remote host is unavailable, or your user is unauthorized; etc.. the exception message should provide additional information (and of course right now we don't know if it fails due to classNotFound or due to connection being refused..so.. post the stacktrace!)

Comment: "Connection refused" - Hint: SQLEXPRESS instances almost never listen on port 1433.

Answer (score 0):

It worked like this:
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-G8057U8;databaseName=Vaporizadores;integratedSecurity=true;";
and i added the sqljdbc_auth.dll to Java bin folder